# Better to use data from table on page or from a pre-made javascript variable - PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, code-organization

I found a few questions that were close, but not quite what I needed, so I'm sorry if this has already been asked.

I have a page with a table filled in with PHP using data from a database. The user can select a row in the table and it will auto fill the data from that row into an edit section farther down the page.

My question is, when filling the edit fields, is it better to pull the data straight from the table or have PHP save the same data as the table in a javascript variable ahead of time and pull it from that?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to edit the data you must access from the database and fill up the form, not by the js code cause it's bad practice.

Comment: Is there a reason why it is considered bad practice? If the data is already accessed from the database for the table when the page is loaded, why not re-use the data you already have?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but, data displayed in a table could be incorrect if the page has been left open for a while. The record could have been changed by someone else, or by the current user in another tab. Best practice is to always request the most up-to-date data when offering it for edit. Likewise, an edit window left open for an extended period could also have the same issue.